# Type of HL7 Message used to confirm image sent to PACS

Tags: hl7

What is the HL7 message type that is exchanged when the imaging is finished and the image is ready to be viewed ?
If it's ORM, What segment shall I use to map it to my "Image_Sent" field in my PACS DB ?
Please note that this message is requested by HIS from PACS.

Thanks in advance.
Abdallah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use an `ORM^O01` message.

Our PACS sends an ORM^O01 in event of completed study. The "study completed" event is mapped by `ORC-1` value of `SC` (Status Changed) and `ORC-5` value of `CM` (Completed).

Hope it helps!